# Shouln't this be a var instead of let?

Tags: swift

Hi guys so I have an issue with understanding this code:

```
struct Point {
    // Passing in values
    // X = 1
    let x: Int
    // y = 1
    let y: Int

    func surroundingPoints(withRange range: Int = 1) -> [Point] {
        var results: [Point] = []
        for xCoord in (x-range)...(x+range) {
            for yCoord in (y-range)...(y+range) {
                let coordinatePoint = Point(x: xCoord, y: yCoord)
                results.append(coordinatePoint)
                print(coordinatePoint)
            }
        }
        return results
    }
}

// Creating an instance and assigning to a constant called coordinatePoint

let coordinatePoint = Point(x: 1, y: 1)
print(coordinatePoint)

// Calling the function inside Point instance
coordinatePoint.surroundingPoints()
print(coordinatePoint)
```

Shouldn't

```
let coordinatePoint = Point(x: xCoord, y: yCoord)
```

be a var instead of a let? As it's changing it's value each time around the for loop? or is it created and destroyed each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable is created and destroyed each time, so either would work just fine. It would be a different story if you had defined `coordinatePoint` above the for loop. In this case, you would have to use `var`.

Comment: Thank you! I suspect that may have been the case but I wasn't completely sure. So variables and constants created inside loops are destroyed after each loop has completed?

Comment: Yes they are. Each iteration of the loop is independent of the previous, except where the loop modifies something that was declared outside of itself.

Comment: @TomWayne, yes, this is the intent of it. Don't think of it in terms of performance though, because the compiler is allowed to be "smart" about it.

Comment: What @zneak means is that sometimes the compiler makes it so the machine code doesn't actually destroy the variable for efficiency, but you need not worry about what the computer actually does on the inside. The compiler will always make it so it behaves as if the variable were destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

No - coordinatePoint inside the loop is locally scoped to that inner loop.  It ceases to exist directly after the print and is recreated on the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

No. `coordinatePoint` is created and then destroyed once for each iteration of the for loop. (Its scope is limited to the for loop it is declared inside.) This is just like how a local variable in a function will be created and destroyed once each time you invoke the function. 
If you wanted to use a var instead of a let, then you would declare it outside the scope of the for loop as follows:

```
func surroundingPoints(withRange range: Int = 1) -> [Point] {
    var results: [Point] = []
    var coordinatePoint: Point
    for xCoord in (x-range)...(x+range) {
        for yCoord in (y-range)...(y+range) {
            coordinatePoint = Point(x: xCoord, y: yCoord)
            results.append(coordinatePoint)
            print(coordinatePoint)
        }
    }
    return results
}
```

Now `coordinatePoint` is created only once per invocation of the method. There's no particular advantage to doing so however, and using a let is probably preferable from a stylistic point of view.

Answer (score 0):

`let` or `var`, it depends on scope of you will use it. If you want change value after use in the same scope, you have to use `var`. If not you will use `let`. When you run this scope it will create and end scope it will be destroyed.